# Distributed system on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, system, distributed

How do I create a cluster of computers in Amazon EC2? What are the best practices for security? Can I access other machines in the local network?

Thanks!

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way AWS likes to do this is by utilizing security groups as firewall.

Generally each instance has a security group - the minimum is one called `default`. This security group allows you to white-list where *others* can connect to.

The *others* include:

- single ip addresses
- ip networks
- other security groups
- everyone

### Example

- database server:

  - `db.example.org`
  - security groups:

    - default
    - database
- two application servers:

  - `app1.example.org`
  - `app2.example.org`
  - security groups:

    - default
    - appserver

I assume these instances run and have the security groups associated with them. If not -- it's pretty trivial using the AWS console. Let me know if you need pointers.

In my examples, I use the [AWS EC2 CLI tools](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351).

First, open port 80 (web) on the appservers for everyone:

```
ec2-authorize appserver -p 80
```

This is the CLI command [`ec2-authorize`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-10-01/CLTRG-authorize.html), but you can do it on the [AWS Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as well. The above command allows everyone to connect to port 80 on your instances when the have the `appserver` group -- e.g. using a browser to go to your website.

Then allow the application servers to connect to your database server:

```
ec2-authorize database -u YOURAWSUSERACCOUNTID -o appservers
```

This will allow each instance that gets the group `appservers` to connect to any open port on the database server. The `YOURAWSUSERACCOUNTID` can be found when you log into the console and go to "Account > Security Credentials > Account Identifiers" (at the bottom of the page).

Changes to the security groups sometimes take a while to become active. It's best when they are done before the instance is started.

HTH